# Wireframe and halo together

Tags: materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, wireframe

I have a simple mesh and like to render it as halo and wireframe.

Unfortunately they render only wireframe OR halo. I tried to mix halo and wireframe but i guess it affects only to the color.

[image]

What i also tried to assign the halo material to vertices and the wireframe material to the edges.

Any idea?

Comment: Would adding the shaders work? (Set Mix blending mode to Add)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the trick here is having to overlapping objects with different materials.

If you make an instance of eachoder they'll virtually be one and the same object, changes to the mesh will propagate to other clones seamlessly and each can have it's own material one with halo, other with wireframe.

Make sure you apply materials *By Object* instead of *By Data* otherwise you won't be able to have different materials per object.

[image: Wire + Halo]

Comment: I already did this successfully too but in my next step i like to animate the deformation of the mesh (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCBaLcsMCRs&t=0m43s) but by cloning the mesh i must first animte the mesh. How to keep the order of materilaize and then animate?

Comment: If you animate through shape keys animations should propagate automatically to all instances. Otherwise clone the object after creating the animation and re apply the materials.