# How can I render a material with wireframe and keep the faces showing, in the BGE?

Tags: game-engine, wireframe

OK so I know how to render a material with just wireframe only, but when the game engine is on, the material becomes completely transparent and only displays the wireframe with the color i gave it in the material, that's expected, but is there a way for me to render the wireframe while keeping the faces visible when game engine is running?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57134/wireframe-and-halo-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your object then

`Properties Panel -> Object -> Display -> Maximum Draw Type -> Wireframe`

Running in game mode should use whatever material you have assigned to your object.

Object mode:

[image]

Game mode:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome!! Could you please vote up my answer? I am in desperate need to reach 50 rep to be able to comment!! Thx

Comment: I did, but since i haven't reached 15 reputations, the site wont allow me to publicly change your vote. Once I reach 15 Reputation, I'll be able to publicly vote for answers. I'm sorry man I'm trying my best to reach 15.

Comment: Sorry I meant accept my answer, not upvote it! Thx.

Comment: Sorry, how do i up vote it?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: OK I accepted it :)